# Golang pointer of type within a struct

Tags: go

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import "fmt"

type Testing struct {
    firstname string
}

type Another struct {
    *Testing
}

func main() {
    var f = Another{firstname: "sasdf"}
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```

Here I've used a pointer in the struct. Its something i've seen used in repository. But i'm not understanding.

What does this do? First i expected it would extend the properties of Testing struct. This ins't true.

From my inspected the Another struct may have a Testing property that holds a value. Giving it `var f = Another{Testing: &Testing{firstname: "afsdf"}}` and printing yields a struct containing a memory address. Do this syntax is a new struct with a property that contains a pointer to a object of T named the name of the type

Comment: How does that code compile? `.\so.go:16:21: cannot use promoted field Testing.firstname in struct literal of type Another`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an embedded field.

> A field or method `f` of an embedded field in a struct `x` is called promoted if `x.f` is a legal selector that denotes that field or method `f`.
> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they cannot be used as field names in composite literals of the struct.

The last quoted sentence is why the composite literal `Another{firstname: "sasdf"}` did not work.